# Combine two or more activity into one - android

Tags: android

Below is my activity.I have over 50 recipes in my app in which the activity file has the same content except that the xml layout file name. How can I combine all these files into one?

I have a listview and listitems. Whenever a listitem is pressed, it will be redirected to its corresponding activity through intent. So, will it be affected if I club all these activities into one?

```
public class recipe1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe1);
        // To make text scrollable
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewText);         
        txt.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        txt.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());       
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Heading); 
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    }   
}
```

Comment: No it won't. Ideally, you have a `fragment_receipe.xml` and `activity_main.xml`. On `listItemClick` in MainActivity,  instantiate a new `ReceipeFragment`, pass in arguments to display the selected recipe and show the fragment.

Comment: I have 5 tabs totally. In each tab i have  a listview and listitems. From there when a listitem is pressed, it will be redirected to its activity. I have 50 class and .xml files individually for all. I am planning to club all those 50 .class and 50 .xml files into one.

Comment: But the content of the xml layout's differ a bit. If suppose it is recipe1, then the image of recipe1 with its content will be loaded. Similarly for all. So, how can I handle this for all 50?

Comment: You could make single xml file or Json and parse them using only one activity and split it accordingly to list in 5 tabs.

Comment: If possible can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Sowndarya, yeap, receipe1 to recipe50 can use the same `fragment_receipe.xml` layout as long as they have the same structure. When a listItem is clicked, you just need to instantiate a new ReceipeFragment, pass in the arguments specific to RecipeX and display the fragment.

Comment: http://json.org/example make JSON with all your recipes in with same tag names. parse them.. easy and simple. start your app from scratch imo.

Comment: @Dhinakaran Thennarasu: Thanks I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing in terms of efforts/value ratio you can do is to keep only one activity (let's call it `RecipeActivity`) to display a recipe, but keep on duplicating the xml layouts. You can pass the recipe id into the intent when you launch the recipe activity, and in recipe activity you can extract the recipe id from intent and set the content based on that. Roughly like this:

```
// in MainActivity
public final String RECIPE_ID = "RECIPE_ID";
...
Intent recipeIntent = new Intent(this, RecipeActivity.class);
recipeIntent.putExtra(RECIPE_ID, recipeId);//where recipeId is an index of recipe user has clicked on
startActivity(recipeIntent);

// in RecipeActivity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    int recipeId = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.RECIPE_ID, 0);
    switch (recipeId) {
        case 1: setContentView(R.layout.recipe1); break;
        case 2: setContentView(R.layout.recipe2); break;
        ...
        default: throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong recipe id");
    }
    ...
}
```

If you also want to avoid xml layout duplication, you can extract the common parts into one xml layout, and set the rest of the content programmatically based on the recipe id. I mean something like this:

```
// in RecipeActivity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ImageView recipeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
    TextView recipeDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipe_description);
    switch (recipeId) {
        case 1: { 
            recipeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recipe_1_image); 
            recipeDescription.setText(R.string.recipe_1_description);
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much :) It worked. Sorry for a very late reply.

Comment: If it worked for you, please mark this answer as accepted, so that future users of StackOverflow will benefit from this knowledge (and I'll get a little reputation bump).